# Using ipysheet, how do I adjust the column width for an index column?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to work through the simple ipysheet example below and have not been able to find a way to increase the column width associated with the date index in the resulting sheet in a Jupyter Notebook

```
import ipysheet as ip  
import pandas as pd  

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)  
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))  
sheet = ip.from_dataframe(df)  
display(sheet)
```

[Resulting Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOAH9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, and don't see anything in the code that indicates this is possible.

You can see in the [ipysheet code](https://ipysheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/ipysheet/sheet.html#Sheet) that Sheet extends [`ipywidget.DOMWidget`](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/master/ipywidgets/widgets/domwidget.py), which in turn extends [`ipywidget.Widget`](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/master/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py). You can probably send some custom CSS into the constructor that will help it render the way you want but that's going to take a lot of research.

The workaround is to reset the index on your DataFrame so that `dates` is just a column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))  
df = df.reset_index()
sheet = ip.from_dataframe(df)
```

Not exactly what you want, but for my purposes it's definitely good enough.